# Add a subdomain as an exception in hotlinking

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I used this code in my `.htaccess` file and it is working great to prevent hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|pdf|wav|wmv|wma|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|mp3|zip?)$ - [F]
```

Now I want to allow one of my subdomains (`cdn.example.com`) to access my files using a GET request.

It is not possible to add http_reffer to my GET request! I should only handle it with `.htaccess`.

How should I add my subdomain as an exception in this code?

Comment: Do you man that the edge nodes need to be able to fetch the content from your origin server?  If so, what CDN provider are you using?  What user agent do they use to fetch files from your origin?

Comment: No , i have not any cdn provider . i have another server for cdn.mydomain.com . and on that server i have a php script that will convert images to specific format . i should allow this script to read images from main domain. but the htaccess not allowing my subdomain to read images from main domain.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1095467/add-subdomain-as-exception-in-hotlinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
> ```

Use the following *condition* instead to allow for an optional `cdn` subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://(cdn\.)?\1/
```

(The trailing `.*` is not required.)

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> It is not possible to add http_reffer to my GET request!

Not sure exactly what you mean by this, but if the `Referer` header is not being sent with these requests for some reason (perhaps you have a restrictive Referrer-Policy?) then you will likely need to allow an *empty* referer.

To allow an *empty* `Referer`, add the following as the first *condition*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
:
```

However, this will also allow *direct* requests. But due to the unreliable nature of the `Referer` header you really need to allow an *empty* `Referer` header anyway since some legitimate users might be suppressing it.

*Aside:* These directives to prevent hotlinking also block search engines - if that is a concern?

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> i have another server for cdn.mydomain.com . and on that server i have a php script that will convert images to specific format . i should allow this script to read images from main domain
> :
> i can't edit that php script to change request method

Ideally, the script would be sending a custom HTTP request header indicating that the request is coming from your "CDN". You could then check for this in the above directive to allow the request.

If all these requests are coming directly from this other server then you can perhaps allow all requests from this server - identified by the server's IP address.

For example, if `203.0.113.111` is your server's IP address, then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.0.113.111
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|pdf|wav|wmv|wma|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|mp3|zip?)$ - [F]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but still not working after adding this condition

Comment: @jeff What do you mean by "It is not possible to add http_reffer to my GET request!" - are you suggesting the `Referer` is not being sent for these requests? I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes the "Referer" is not sending to main domain , because developer used "imagecreatefromjpeg" in that script and i can't edit that php script to change request method. i used your updated code , but now the problem is all users have direct access to files as you mentioned.i need something like this : if (request is not from cdn ){ block access }

Comment: @jeff Ah, I see. (The script _should_ be sending a custom header in order to identify itself to the target server, although maybe not. Have you examined the HTTP requests to confirm this is not the case?) Alternatively, you could perhaps allow the IP address of the server from which the script is running. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. your answer solved my issue 